# Does the order of operations in a transaction matter?

Tags: database, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS DynamoDB and I am reading its low-level API document.

In TransactWriteItems part, it mentions that:

[image]

I wonder why here mentions it is an ordered array. Because in a single transaction, no two of operations can operate on the same item, so the order of operations in a transaction should not matter.

Is this just special in DynamoDB or is this the normal case that order of operations in a transaction matters?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "in a single transaction, no two of operations can operate on the same item"?  You can, for example, update a column in a table twice in a single transaction without any issues

Comment: But in the picture it says so, at the end of the first paragraph

Comment: @camba1 columns are not really a useful concept when reasoning about DynamoDB. Each item defines its own attributes independently of any other items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the order does not matter.

For the client that is requesting the transaction, the order does not matter because

- You cannot have more than one operation in your transaction for a single item.
- You cannot use the results of one operation as an input to another operation in the same transaction.
- Aside from the uniqueness of the primary key, there is no enforced dependency (nor enforced non/anti-dependency) between any items in the same table.
- There are no dependencies between items in different tables (such as a foreign key requirement) that DynamoDB enforces.

In summary, all of the operations in a DynamoDB transaction are completely independent of each other at the database level except for the fact that they are in the same transaction. Any dependency between the operations exists only in the application/business logic that you create.

For clients that are viewing the transaction from the outside (ie. did not send that particular transaction request), the order of the operations in the transaction does not matter because the point of a transaction is that all the parts of the transaction occur atomically. To clients who did not create that transaction, it appears that all parts of the transaction happen simultaneously.